# Why am I not redirected using router.navigate() in After successful registration and login of a user in Angular11?

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase-authentication, registration, user-registration

This question may seem long, but really important for me. I am successfuly be able to register a new user in firebase but not redirected to '/chatroomlist' path. I tried all possible ways please help me!!

app.module.ts

```
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component'
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ChatroomlistComponent } from './chatroomlist/chatroomlist.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ChatroomlistComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'chatroomlist', component: ChatroomlistComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  register(email: any, password: any){
    return firebase.default.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['chatroomlist']); // here, .then() never works. It is not redirected
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  login(email: any, password: any){
    return firebase.default.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        
        this.router.navigate(['chatroomlist']);  //this path is also not getting redirected. I tried ['/chatroomlist'] too. but it's not working
      }).catch((error) => 
        console.log(error)
      )
  }
}
```

register.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent  {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  register(email: any, password: any){
    this.authService.register(email, password);
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }

  login(email: any, password: any) {
    this.authService.login(email, password);
  }
}
```

register.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Registration</h2><br>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        <input  #email type="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input #password type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="register(email.value, password.value)">Register</button><br>
        <a routerLink="/login">Already a user? Please Login here!</a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Login</h2><br>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input  #email type="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input #password type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="login(email.value, password.value)">Login</button><br>
            <a routerLink="/register">New user? Register here!</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the router.navigate in the component instaed of the service, because components is what you use in the router:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'chatroomlist', component: ChatroomlistComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
    ])
```

So try now returning a promise from the service:

```
register(email:string, password:string){
    return new Promise((resolve, rejected)=> {
      this.AngularAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(user => {
        resolve(user)
      }).catch(err => rejected(err));
    });
  }
```

And in the register component:

```
register(email: any, password: any){
    this.authService.register(email, password).then(this.router.navigate(['chatroomlist']));
  }
```

Remember to add the router to the constructor

Comment: Thanks buddy, but still not redirected to 'chatroomlist' page.

Comment: Can you show me again the changes you did?

Comment: auth.component.ts-->(1) In constructor `constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }` , (2) Register calling(register.component.ts: `this.authService.register(email, password).then(() => this.router.navigate(['chatroomlist']));` , (3) Commented navigate part in method: `register(email: any, password: any){
    return firebase.default.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)}`

Comment: Are you be able to understand here in the comment?

Comment: I edited the post to show it more clearly, but check that you are calling everything correctly and you have the service in the appModule, etc. Hope you find the solution

Comment: I appreciate your help. The problem is not resolved, but one thing is clear that the code in .then() function is not even running after once user is created. I wrote `.then(() => console.log('Inside Register'))`. It is not getting printed in console.

Comment: Place a .catch section to know if the function is getting called

Comment: Yes, I already did it, but no improvement!